# vbs not saving as a .vbs

Tags: vbscript, notepad

So I have this problem for a little problem right now. I write a simple .vbs script,

```
x=msgbox("test",18,"test")
```

which is total perfect, right?
Now everytime I try to save this file like [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlAxC.png)

It's Dutch for a save as .txt file, but as extension .vbs.
Now I'm curious how stupid I am, or how I'm going to fix this.

Comment: Enclose the name in quotes to override automatic extension appending. `"filename.vbs"`. This occurs when explorer's view setting is to hide extensions (the default - but most advanced users change it).

Comment: saving it as "test.vbs"

and select All Files (*.*) in dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, it is saving it as "test.vbs.txt".

Click the "Save as type" (Opslaan als) dropdown box and select `All Files (*.*)` (alle dateien?).  After that it should save as "test.vbs" as you expect.

Answer (score -1):

It's saving it as a .txt file because the dialog is set to save with that type. You can either select `All Files (*.*)` from the dropdown or you can surround the file name in quotes to save it exactly as shown.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. It showed up like the notepad from windows 7 (if I'm right)
http://prntscr.com/avduxq
Now that's a printscreen of a normal .txt file, and a .vbs file.

Comment: Thay may be fine. It depends whether you have a file type handler registered or not. What happens when you double click it? What file type does it say if you right-click and choose `Properties...`?

Comment: I got it! I entered properties and it said "open with notepad" so I changed that to "Microsoft Windows based script host" or something and now I get the right icon and everything works!

Comment: @JeroenSteens There you go! Those file type handlers can cause some unpredictable behavior when they inadvertently get changed from their defaults.